# ts type check by interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
interface ClockConstructor {
  new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
  tick(): void;
}

function createClock(
  ctor: ClockConstructor,
  hour: number,
  minute: number
): ClockInterface {
  return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("beep beep");
  }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number, m: number, s: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("tick tock");
  }
}

class CCClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number, m: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("tick tick");
  }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17); // why not get type check error
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32); // get type check error
let CCyes = createClock(CCClock, 7, 32);
```

**I am looking for the example and do some practices. The "DigitalClock" missed the "minute" param.Why the "DigitalClock" do not has the tyoe check error.**

```
This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review yesterday by Cristik, BDL, SiKing, David Maze.
function printLabel(labelledObj: { label: string; test: string }) {
  console.log(labelledObj.label);
}

let myObj = {label: "Size 10 Object" };
printLabel(myObj);
```

**The "myObj" params will get error. So what's wrong with the interface verification? If I missed some point?**

Comment: Because even if `DigitalClock` receives an extra parameter it does not expect, nothing bad should happen.. If `AnalogClock` does not receive the expected `s` parameter, it might not function correctly. If you make theparameter optional, then `AnalocClock` will also be accepted (`constructor(h: number, m: number, s?: number)`)

Comment: My understanding of this interface “ClockConstructor ” is strongly typed matching. But why the "digital" can missed the param

Comment: Because it doesn't cause any runtime errors. There is no danger in the caller passing more parameters and `Digital` clock ignoring them. `Array.map` accepts a callback with 3 parameters, people usually pass in a function that accepts only one parameter. The one they are interested in, the item. Should typescript complain there too ?

Comment: I add another example as fallow. 
There is doubt between these two examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a relation ship between your classes, a generic will be the way to go.

One solution could be as follow :

```
interface ClockInterface<Params> {
    tick(): void
}

// The shared constructor type 
type ConstructorFunction<T> = new (args: T) => ClockInterface<T>;


function createClock<P>(
    ctor: ConstructorFunction<P>,
    params: P,
): ClockInterface<P> {
    return new ctor(params);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface<{ h: number }> {
    constructor(params: { h: number }) {}
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface<{ h: number, m: number, s: number }> {
    constructor(params: { h: number, m: number, s: number }) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

class CCClock implements ClockInterface<{ h: number, m: number }> {
    constructor(params: { h: number, m: number }) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tick");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, { h: 12 }); // why not get type check error
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, { h: 7, m: 32, s: 2 }); // get type check error
let CCyes = createClock(CCClock, { h: 7, m: 32 });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBsD2CDWBJcaeJAHgAU4o4BbAZwD5kBvAWAChlPkxhcAKAJQAuZADdMwACbsAvuzABPAA4pUmELTBQArgjCYoAMW0g9wdSQAqjALzIQEAO7I+lAOa0RlgchuMM2PiEsIgQVvQA3OzRbDAmZurICFAQcJABuOT0fOxcSfpQImoaWroFxqY8FmT0ADS5XEqUNJ7IZPVswmhYuASQIaQ1zA2cKWDaUCD2TvkGfE1UdAJRbHJs7AjocLS0yAAiwG7AYHDoGTjIwNRK6BDUEOC7531EoSRMyAAWIiDa1ABG0GQMkYrA4XAQ6k0Oj0cwWLREH2+9j+gKgwJ8TDWeR4-ExIzySShmFuADosG4+AAiQEQJTIWlKKnLAlrNabba7ACCIFOmDc50u11u90e3UCLwGYSRP1R0FqyGosoB8uQrV+KvRIOG4M4kJKMIK82adERX2VaIVSpRmoV6rlWsxwIJuJwgh1hIhxLJFOpru4gWZKzybJiHJ2aFQgquNzuDzATx6QX6xGl5ptlsVFqB2rBeX10LKcJNrRlGdV1o1aIxzGduu4vDd+Pr+e9EHJ-L9jYbuCDrNkMVuYGQkkOx1OviSKTSEHOfAORxOZyTCrLAEYAEwYiLIAD0u+Qjk+CnsmGHbggw8UKiSnwguGQ0CgBnYQ+QcF5FMnyVS6STfB5PkBRXWtkQAditEQAGYNztEQtxkZY9wPC8r2UFAEDvB8nxfNg3yjBQIF2OwfxnOco3OVd0wgrNkBg7cgA)

Comment: My understanding of this interface “ClockConstructor ” is strongly typed matching. But why the "digital" can missed the param.

Comment: And Thank you to give the another solution.